# How to create a 64 bit desktop application (AIR) using Flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, air

I need to convert my adobe air application (using Flex 4.6.0.) into 64 bit desktop application (Mac OS and Windows).

Could you explain how to do ?

Indeed, macOS Catalina (macOS 10.15) won't support 32 bit apps !

So I need to find an alternative quickly.

Thanks for helping.

Best regard

Answer (score 1):

In order to update to 64 bit, you will have to update your sdk. 4.6 version is very old (2012 maybe?).

First update your SDK to [AIR 32](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html).

Then you can use tag `<architecture>64</architecture>` in the application.xml file to force 64bit compile.

This works both in windows and mac for desktop apps.