# Error when targetting 64-bit platform with Adobe AIR SDK by HARMAN

Tags: flash, air

I have the following `application.xml` that I am using to create a captive runtime bundle on Windows, targeting the 64-bit architecture:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0"> 
    <id>AppName</id> 
    <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber> 
    <filename>AppName</filename>
    <architecture>64</architecture>
    <initialWindow> 
        <content>AppName.swf</content> 
        <visible>true</visible> 
        <width>960</width> 
        <height>540</height> 
    </initialWindow> 
</application>
```

I am using `<architecture>64</architecture>` as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57680161/3049315) answer.

The command that I am using to create the package is as follows:

```
adt.bat -package -keystore AppName.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -target bundle AppName application.xml AppName.swf
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> error 103 : application.architecture is an unexpected element/attribute

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that updating the namespace from `http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0` to `http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/33.1` has fixed it.

The last segment of the namespace, "3.0", specifies the version of the runtime required by the application, as explained [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html).

My guess is that 3.0 runtime is too old and didn't have 64-bit support. 33.1 runtime is from [Adobe AIR SDK by HARMAN](https://airsdk.harman.com/download). [Here](https://blog.adobe.com/en/2019/05/30/the-future-of-adobe-air.html) is an interesting blog article explaining the future of Adobe AIR.